# Writing an HD Game in Staged 3D

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, starling-framework

I'm trying to write a 2D Game using Starling, and most textures are up to 4k, and I'm getting a resource limit exception.

Is there a way or an algorithm, idea, to get HD Textures and use them with that limited texture resources in stage3d ? Compression ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stage3D (which Starling uses underneath) has a max texture size of 2048x2048. If your textures are larger than this, then you are going to have to split them and stitch them together at runtime.

If you find yourself running out of memory (rather than the dimensional size limit) then you can look into compression using [ATF](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flashruntimes/articles/atf-users-guide.html) textures.